# PHP / Regex: detect string after ?>

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a project which has thousands of php files and i'm trying to detect the ones with invalid closing tags, which means eg. ?> followed by a line break.
how can i regex for ?> followed by line breaks or whatever?

i've tried this pattern but it didn't work:

```
\?>(\n)
```

Comment: So what did you do to solve the issue ?

Comment: Why would that be invalid anyway?

Comment: invalid as they're being used in context of ajax which would return carriage returns causing invalid json data

Comment: The PHP regex documentation is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php and this site is good for testing: https://regex101.com/. See what you can come up with, add it to your post, and we can help you more.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to remove all the ending `?>` tags? That way the potential new lines or spaces won't be outputted.

Comment: Try `\?>$`, should do the job.

Comment: @Emilio that's the point, they need to find them first.

Comment: removing all ?> would take too long .. i'm requiring a quick solution/fix by finding all those "hidden" linebreaks :)

Comment: `preg_match('~\?>\R~', $text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\?>)(\s)+$
```

`(?<=\?>)` : positive lookbehind to find `?>` (but not capture it)

`(\s)+` to find any combinaison of spaces, new lines, tabulations, ... after the tag

`$` to match the end of the string